How to encode item features with high number of categories for recommendation
For the recommendation problem I am working on, there are around 50000 unique brands and 3 level product categories, level_1_cat (50 categories), level_2_cat (100 categories) and level_3_cat (1000 categories). All these item features are represented by integers only. So far I have tried binary-encoding, label-encoding and target-encoding for my lightfm model. With binary-encoding and label-encoding, the results were worse than not using any item features. With target-encoding, the result were similar to not using any item features. I am wondering what else I can try.

I like count encoding. There is also hash encoding. Also, don't you have any way to bin the brands? is the result worse if you remove the brands feature? Another idea would be to find a dataset/table on internet that links the categorical feature to a numeric feature that could be of interest eg instead of brands use the last revenue/year or the number of employees, ...

removing brands did not make much difference. All features are integers only. That's why I can't bin the brands. Maybe there is a way to cluster the brands based on customer interactions? If similar users interacted with similar brands etc.
